# How to describe a gazette to stakeholders in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin

Suppose a university sends a periodic magazine or gazette out to alumni, companies, and other stakeholders.
What would be a good Latin word for this kind of a publication?
Would it be simply *nuntii*?
Perhaps something like *acta diurna* would be appropriate, but I don't want to imply that it is published every day.

What phrase would you use and why?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *acta ordinaria*.

The word *ordo* means not just 'a series', but an orderly or even a regular series. The derived adjective *ordinarius* neatly fits the idea of a regular series of publications; and when the subjects of these are things done or decisions made, the better word is *acta* rather than *nuntii*.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that this kind of thing could be simply called ***acta*** when it comes with the name of the university.
For example, for the University of Jyväskylä we could have *Acta Granivicensia* or *Acta Universitatis Granivicensis*.
(Or you can replace *Granivicensis* with *Jyväskyläensis*.)

The word *acta* won't work alone and isn't a good overall name for the concept, but I think this word communicates the type of publication sufficiently well.
For a standalone word that could be used for this kind of publication irrespective of the institution, Tom Cotton's suggestion is excellent.

I should remark that *acta* is also used for scientific journals.
One of the highest-ranking ones in mathematics is *Acta Mathematica*.